# Is there a fully online IDE for testing out simple algorithms

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic, ide

I was watching one of those incredibly retarded tv quiz money scams last night as I was reading reddit and they posed the question:

> if you wrote down all the numbers between 32 to 287 how may times would you write down the number 6?

So I did some quick maths in my head (there are 11 sixes in each 100, there are two hundreds in between the two numbers and then there are six more = 22 + 6 = 28). The first caller rings up and says 28.

I am not great at maths in my head but I could think of a pretty easy for loop that would figure it out, but there is no way I was going to go through the hassle of installing an IDE on my home machine just to write five lines of code. My question:

**Is there a website where I can write simple algorithms like this and compile them and get results all in-browser without having to install any crap or jump through any hoops?**

Comment: Aren't there 20 sixes in each 100? 6, 16, 26, 36, 46, 56, 60 - 69, 76, 86 and 96?

Comment: indeed; that's what I was missing :)

Comment: I know this isn't what you were asking, but there must be 40 from 32 to 231, plus another 16, giving 56, but I would not be confident enough to ring up the show with that answer :)

Comment: Did the caller saying "28" win this quiz??

Comment: nope, but I did wonder because I remember watching an UK channel a few years ago, at the height of the phone quiz scandal, and someone definitely rang up saying the correct answer and was rejected :/

Comment: you can do this in our pluggable

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Code Pad](http://codepad.org/) supports a lot of programming languages, is free and doesn't require registration.

Answer (score 6):

There is also web based interpreters for Python:

http://try-python.mired.org/

And for Ruby:

http://tryruby.hobix.com/

Example for the Python online interpreter:

```
Python 2.5.2 (r252:60911, May 29 2008, 09:50:36) [C] on sunos5
Type "help", "copyright", "credits", or "license" for more information.
>>> total=0
>>> for a in range(32,288):
...    total = total + str(a).count('6')
... 
>>> total
56
```

Comment: The reason range(32,288) was used is because the built-in Python range() function returns a list of integers one less than the stop argument. Not that it would make a difference here of course, 287 contains no sixes :)

Answer (score 3):

Nowadays there's also the [ideone.com](http://ideone.com/). It supports a large variety of programming languages, including esoteric ones.

Answer (score 2):

This answer is going to be language specific. For the best answer, javascript would work well. Since it already runs in the browser, writing an interpreter that runs in the browser is a piece of cake. Just google for "javascript interpreter" and you'll get a bunch of hits.

Answer (score 2):

If you can write the algorithms in Javascript, use [Project Bespin](https://bespin.mozilla.com/).

> Bespin is a Mozilla Labs experiment that proposes an open, extensible web-based framework for code editing that aims to increase developer productivity, enable compelling user experiences, and promote the use of open standards.

Answer (score 2):

http://compilr.com has IDE support for C#, java, c++, ruby, php, vb.  And compile support for java.

Answer (score 2):

[Codiad](http://codiad.com) or [Codiad++](http://couleetechlink.com/new2/codiad) for the cpp version.

Answer (score 1):

There's an online "live demo" for the LUA language here: http://www.lua.org/demo.html

Answer (score 1):

There is an online Ruby interpreter at:
http://tryruby.hobix.com/

It has a pretty good tutorial too to help you learn Ruby as you go.

Answer (score 1):

There's a whole bunch of BASIC emulators!

http://www.vavasour.ca/jeff/level1/simulator.html

Great for some instant

```
10 PRINT "HELLO"
20 GOTO 10
```

Answer (score 1):

The best online tool I've found (except for codepad) is http://jsfiddle.net/

You are able to write the HTML, CSS and JavaScript for your app. You can choose from 10 JavaScript frameworks (I recommend jQuery for simple tests). And to test you only need to press the Run buttons. Allows for online saving (pastebin-like), which is also good.